# SetTimeout. Как сделать внутри цикла?

Tags: javascript, циклы

```
<script>
var height = window.innerHeight;
var width = window.innerWidth;

{
function change_bg() {
    var i = 1; // вот тут у меня он = 1
    document.write("<div id='bg' style='height:" + height + "px; width:" + width + "px; background-image:url(img/bg" + i + ".jpg);'></div>");
}

setTimeout(change_bg(), 3000);
    // тут я хочу сделать после setTimeout i++. Чтобы он сперва показывал bg1.jpg, а через 3 сек - bg2.jpg. А потом обнулить счетчик и начать заново.

</script>
```

Как я могу сделать так? Для этого мне надо чтобы вся эта функция была внутри цикла. А вот какого, не могу ставить. Помогите разобраться

Answer (score 5):

```
<script>
var height = window.innerHeight;
var width = window.innerWidth;

var i = 1;

function change_bg() {
    document.write("<div id='bg' style='height:" + height + "px; width:" + width + "px; background-image:url(img/bg" + i + ".jpg);'></div>");
    if (i>10) i = 1; else i++;
    }

setInterval(change_bg, 3000);
</script>
```

Comment: я бы это еще в closure завернул, чтобы переменные от глобального доступа защитить

    <script>
    (function() {
      //ваш код
    })()
    </script>

Comment: Я бы тоже, на самом деле, но всему своё время ;)

Comment: он только две фотки показывает и останавливается. Почему так?

Comment: Есть ошибки в консоли?

Comment: Логично, что функция выполнится всего 2 раза.

Comment: @lampa, я что-то с утра протупил - действительно, setInterval же :)

Answer (score 3):

Надо помнить, что метод `document.write()` работает корректно только тогда, когда документ еще не загружен. Из этого следует, что этот метод надо заменить.

Смену изображения по таймауту делают либо с помощью `setTimeout()`, как у вас, либо с помощью `setInterval()`. Но у каждой функции свои нюансы.

В общем выходит так:

```
var height = window.innerHeight;
var width = window.innerWidth;
var counter = 1;

// добавляем элемент
document.write("<div id='bg' style='height:" + height + "px; width:" + width + "px;'></div>");

/**
 * данная конструкция позволит запустить
 * функцию сразу после её объявления
 */
(function change_bg() {
    /** просто изменяем фон у созданного элемента
     *
     * Т.к. у вас всего две картинки, то можно 
     * сократить конструкцию, добавив проверку на
     * четность цифры: counter % 2 
     * - если цифра переменной counter четная, то 
     * подставляем цифру 1, иначе 2.
     */
    document.getElementById('bg').style.backgroundImage = "url(img/bg" + (counter % 2 ? 1 : 2) + ".jpg)";
    // плюсуем счетчик
    counter++;

    // добавляем таймер для повторного вызова этой функции
    setTimeout(change_bg, 1000);
})();
```

Да, выглядит запутанно на первый взгляд, но при понимании добавляет +100 к скиллу.

Answer (score 2):

i++ делайте внутри функции change_bg и выведите i в глобали. Больше ничего не надо менять. Цикл не нужен.

```
var height = window.innerHeight;
var width = window.innerWidth;
var i = 1; // вот тут у меня он = 1

function change_bg() {

    document.write("<div id='bg' style='height:" + height + "px; width:" + width + "px; background-image:url(img/bg" + i + ".jpg);'></div>");
if(i>N)i=1; else i++;
}

setTimeout(change_bg, 3000);
```